# Is it possible to initialize a variable from an environment variable at compilation time?

Tags: rust, compile-time-constant

I would like to initialize a variable during compilation time. For example, I would like to initialize the variable `VAR` to `VALUE` when compiling the code:

```
match env::var("VAR") {
    Ok(value) => println!("Ok {}", value),
    Err(e) => println!("Error ({})", e),
};
```

However, I wanted to do it in a `no_std` context, therefore, I cannot use `std::env` to access the environment. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`env::var`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.var.html) does **not** get evaluated at compile time:

> Fetches the environment variable key from the current process.

You are looking for [`std::env!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.env.html) / [`core::env!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/macro.env.html) or [`std::option_env!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.option_env.html) / [`core::option_env!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/macro.option_env.html).

Comment: "rustc-env=VAR=VALUE indicates that the specified environment variable will be added to the environment which the compiler is run within. The value can be then retrieved by the env! macro in the compiled crate. " Copied from https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html. I'm bit confused. What does it mean by "the environment which the compiler is run within?"

Comment: @Dragonight The thing you have quoted seems to agree with me: *retrieved by the `env!` macro*. "the environment which the compiler is run within" would mean "the environment variables set when the compiler runs" (as opposed to "when the produced program runs").