# How can I specify an environment variable using the rustc-env flag?

Tags: rust

I want to set `rustc-env=VAR=VALUE` so that I could access it using `env::var("VAR")` in my code. However, I'm not clear on where to specify it. Can I set the environment variable `VAR` in the Makefile?

Comment: *What* Makefile? Rust does not have Makefiles. [As you already know](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51620782/155423), `env::var` is for  environment variables set *when the program executes*, not when the *compiler* executes.

Comment: *I'm not clear on where to specify it* — where did you learn about it? The [documentation that you linked before](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) tells you where these go; what do you find confusing about it?

Comment: it says "rustc-env=VAR=VALUE indicates that the specified environment variable will be added to the environment which the compiler is run within". I cannot find how and where to specify rustc-env and how to access that variable from the code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### TL;DR

**build.rs**

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-env=VAR=VALUE");
}
```

**src/main.rs**

```
fn main() {
    let var = env!("VAR");
}
```

---

The [documentation that you linked](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) is for a Cargo *build script*:

> The Rust file designated by the `build` command (relative to the package root) will be compiled and invoked before anything else is compiled in the package, allowing your Rust code to depend on the built or generated artifacts. By default Cargo looks up for `"build.rs"` file in a package root (even if you do not specify a value for `build`). Use `build = "custom_build_name.rs"` to specify a custom build name or `build = false` to disable automatic detection of the build script.

On the same page, there's a [section that describes outputs of build.rs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#outputs-of-the-build-script)

> All the lines printed to stdout by a build script are written to a file [...] Any line that starts with `cargo:` is interpreted directly by Cargo. This line must be of the form `cargo:key=value`, like the examples below:
>
> ```
> cargo:rustc-env=FOO=bar
> ```

It then details `rustc-env`:

> `rustc-env=VAR=VALUE` indicates that the specified environment variable will be added to the environment which the compiler is run within. The value can be then retrieved by the `env!` macro in the compiled crate. This is useful for embedding additional metadata in crate's code, such as the hash of Git HEAD or the unique identifier of a continuous integration server.

[`env!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.env.html) is a macro.

---

> access it using `env::var("VAR")`

No. [`env::var`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.var.html) is for reading environment variables set when the program *runs*, not when the program is *compiled*.

See also:

- [Is it possible to initialize a variable from an environment variable at compilation time when using no_std?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51620782/155423)