# How do I set environment variables with Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a dependency listed in Cargo.toml that needs a specific environment variable set. I can run `export FOO=bar` in bash and all works well, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to export this environment variable at compile time with Cargo. I've tried setting the environment variable in `build.rs` via `std::env`, `Command`, and `println!`, all to no effect:

```
// build.rs
fn main() {
    Command::new("ls")
        .env("FOO", "bar")
        .spawn()
        .expect("ls command failed to start");
}
```

```
// build.rs
fn main() {
    std::env::set_var("FOO", "bar");
}
```

```
// build.rs
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-env=FOO=bar");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify an environment variable using the rustc-env flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621642/how-to-specify-an-environment-variable-using-the-rustc-env-flag)

Comment: It is correct English.

It's not a duplicate. I'm trying to set a compile time environment variable. The link speaks of a runtime environment variable.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible, see https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4121.

Comment: What is the dependency in question? How does it use the environment variable?

Comment: try to look at task runners like https://github.com/sagiegurari/cargo-make which enable you to define the env as part of your flow. so when you compile that env will be set first.

Comment: The crate is oidn-rs and it seems to need OIDN_DIR and LD_LIBRARY_PATH set. I've reached out on the issue tracker to see if this is something that can be resolved at the crate level.

I saw cargo-make, but would prefer not to have to use another crate just for this task.

So far it looks like issue 4121 on the Cargo issue tracker is what needs to be implemented.

Comment: @Stargateur it is correct English (source: a lifetime of being English). "but" here not meaning "except", but rather acting as a conjunction for the rest of the following clause.

Answer (score 53):

Since Cargo 1.56, you can use the [configurable-env](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/unstable.html#configurable-env) feature via the `[env]` section in [`config.toml`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html). This is not the same file as `Cargo.toml`, but it can still be set per project:

```
[env]
FOO = "bar"
PATH_TO_SOME_TOOL = { value = "bin/tool", relative = true }
USERNAME = { value = "test_user", force = true }
```

Environment variables set in this section will be applied to the environment of any processes executed by Cargo.

`relative` means the variable represents a path relative to the location of the directory that contains the `.cargo/` directory that contains the `config.toml` file.

`force` means the variable can override an existing environment variable.

For more information about the history of this feature, see the [related GitHub issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4121).

Comment: Awesome! Anything that can be used in the meantime?

Comment: I don't think so, the issue on cargo's repo asking for this feature was closed by the PR implementing this and I haven't seen any alternative. I guess you could use a bash script in the meantime.

Comment: Could you just link to the github issue for completeness? Thanks!

Comment: Added a link at the end

Comment: I upgraded Cargo to `1.52` and created the file: `project root dir > .cargo > config.toml`. But `env::var("FOO")` isn't finding anything. Restarted VSCode, ran my test from terminal and from VSCode.

Comment: Theses are environment variables set for the processes executed by cargo, _not_ for use in the final binary! This is useful for building C dependencies for example.
See 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621642/how-to-specify-an-environment-variable-using-the-rustc-env-flag
to check how to achieve what you want.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on what I'm supposed to write in config.toml?

Comment: Note for people reading this in the future: this feature is stable now.

Comment: Thanks. Edited the post, it is since cargo 1.56
https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#cargo-156-2021-10-21

Comment: Is it possible to set different env vars if --release is set?

Comment: @Felipe when you set `--release`, that's in your CLI. So, I suppose that you can also simply set an environment variable as well, which will overwrite what's defined in `config.toml`

Comment: Is there a way to configure this in `build.rs` itself? I need to find the linker and ar on the host during runtime.